# Replace conditional with polymorphism, but how to do it

Tags: java, oop

Consider a following piece of code:

```
class NumberWrapper {
   boolean negative;
   void setNegativeTrue(boolean isNegative) {
      negative = isNegative;
   }

   void  negateNumber(int x) {
      if (negative) {
          x = x * -1;
      } else {
         x = Math.abs(x);
      }
      return x;
   }
}
```

In code like this, how is it possible to use polymorphism ?

Comment: Is this a homework? What concept of polymorphism do you want to apply? Frankly the current code is no good example. And please provide a better name to your method. `calculate`?? What does it calculate? Give a descriptive name.

Comment: This is a good tutorial for polymorphism: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm. As Rohit Jain commented, the code you've provided isn't really suited for converting to polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the `boolean` parameter which results in two different code paths with two different classes, each implementing one path.

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract void calculate(int x);
}

class NormalFoo extends Foo {
   void calculate(int x) {
      x = Math.abs(x);
      return x;
   }
}

class NegativeFoo extends Foo {
   void calculate(int x) {
       x = x * -1;
      return x;
   }
}
```

Instead of `setNegativeTrue` you create one of those classes and thereby replace the conditional with polymorphism

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum UnaryOperator {

    NEGATE {
        @Override
        public int apply(int x) {
             return -x;
        }
    }, 
    ABS {
        @Override
        public int apply(int x) {
             return Math.abs(x);
        }
    }

    public abstract int apply(int x);
}

class Foo {
    private UnaryOperator operator = UnaryOperator.ABS;

    void setUnaryOperator(UnaryOperator operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    void calculate(int x) {
        return operator.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, although surely too much for what looks like a homework. Still, love the use of enums!

Comment: The enum could be replaced by an interface or abstract class.